# Non English not supported mysql query from $.post jquery codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I need to call ajax via `$.post` for a Non-English keyword but it ends up in encoded format and hence no results. I have my encoding as `UTF-8` and database collation as `utf8_unicode_ci`. Still having the problem. Sharing the Code and the result:

```
//Jquery

  $('form#frm_word').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var s = $('input#s').val();
        var url = '<?php echo site_url('words/get_word'); ?>' + '/' + s;
        $.post(url, function (o) {
            if (o.result == 1) {
                console.log(o.words);
            }
        }, 'json');
    });

Case url: http://localhost/subscription/words/get_word/আমি
Result: SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE w_word LIKE 
'%%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%'{"result":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the value in a variable using segment function like `$this->uri->segment(3)` and then send the parameter in query withing quotes like

```
select * from words where w_word LIKE '$variable%'; 
or
select * from words where w_word = '$variable';
```